# fseek creates infinite loop at run time

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, binaryfiles, fseek

WHAT THE CODE DOES: I read a binary file and sort it. I use a frequency array in order to do so. 
UPDATES:it does do the loop, but it doesn`t write the numbers correctly...

That is the code. I want to write on file after reading from it. I will suprascript what is already written, and that is okey. The problem is I have no error on compiling, but at run time it seems I have an infinite loop. 
The file is binary. I read it byte by byte and that`s also the way I want to write it.

```
while(fread(readChar, sizeof(readChar)/2, 1, inFile)){
    bit = atoi(readChar);
    array[bit] = array[bit] + 1;
}

fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

for( i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    while(array[i] > 0){
        writeChar[0] = array[i]; //do I correctly convert int to char?
        fwite(writeChar, sizeof(readChar)/2, 1, inFile);
        array[i] = array[i] -1;
    }
```

The inFile file declaration is:

```
FILE* inFile = fopen (readFile, "rb+");
```

It reads from the file, but does not write!

Comment: Check the return value from `fread()` for errors.

Comment: isn't `while (fread()..` lacking the closing parenthesis?

Comment: Is the readChar variable by any chance one byte long? Because if yes that could create a loop, since you would infinitely read 1 times zero characters.

Comment: It's not like I don't believe you, but could you provide the declaration of this variable?

Comment: I also note that you have an unmatched parenthesis. The last line of your snippet has a `}`, yet there isn't a `{` to go with it. Perhaps it should be on the line that follows `while(array[i]>0)`? If so, you really should explicitly enclose the contents of the for loop too. The `fwrite` call will only ever be executed once, since the for loop runs the `while (array[i] > 0)` statement 256 times, and that while construct only sets `writechar[0]` to `writechar[i]`. After this while loop contained in the for loop has finished, `frwite` will be called once, as will be `array[i] = array[i]-1;`

Comment: `while(array[i] > 0)` --> `while(array[i] > 0){` ??

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it.

it gets into for and only stays at i=0...creating infinite loop

Comment: Your comment in the code says it doesn't get into the for loop?

Comment: How about using a debugger?

Comment: How about posting something that reproduces the problem?

Comment: writeChar[0] = array[i]; //do I correctly convert int to char?
        fwrite(writeChar, sizeof(readChar)/2, 1, inFile);

I think the problem is here. I vant to convert int to char* because the first parameter of fwrite is char*....but my conversion in wrongly done

Comment: You say you read a file bit by bit. You can't in C. The smallest unit is a byte. The statement `bit = atoi(readChar);` does not what you think it does. Please provide a *complete* compilabale example.

Comment: Both the inner while loop and the outer for loop will terminate (as the code is curently shown). Hence there is no problem, unless here is some side efect from code or declarations not shown. Please provide a complete example that can be compiled and shows the problematic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason for an *infinite* loop I see is, that your array is not initialized. 
After declaration with:

```
int array[256];
```

the elements can have any integer value, also very large ones.
So there are no infinite loops, but some loops can have very much iterations.
You should initialize your array with zeros:

```
int array[256]={0};
```

I don't know the count of elements in your array and if this is the  way you declare it, but if you declare your array like shown, than `={0}` will initialize all members with 0. You also can use a loop:

```
for(int i=0; i < COUNT_OF_ELEMENTS;i++) array[i] = 0;
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention, that your code is only able to sort files with only numbers within.
For that, you have also to change the `conversion` while writing:

```
char writeChar[2]={0};
for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
    while(array[i] > 0){
        _itoa(i,writeChar,10);
        fwrite(writeChar, sizeof(char), 1, inFile);
        array[i] = array[i] -1;
    }
```

File content before:
`12345735280735612385478504873457835489`

File content after:
`00112223333334444455555556777778888889`

Is that what you want?

Comment: @Sasi `array={0}` simply inits first element to `{<whatever_number>}` and all other elements to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior:

`fread()` is used to read a *binary* representation of data.  `atoi()` takes a *textual* represetation of data: a string (a pointer to an array of `char` that is terminated with a `'\0'`.

Unless the data read into `readChar` has one of its bytes set to 0, calling `atoi()` may access data outside `readChar`.

```
fread(readChar, sizeof(readChar)/2, 1, inFile);
bit = atoi(readChar);
```

Code it not reading data "bit by bit"  At @Jens comments: "The smallest unit is a byte." and that is at least 8 bits.